# After Updating Android studio to 3.1.2 , I get "Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error. "

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried looking other similar questions on stackoverflow, they advice us to changw version of "buildToolsVersion" but I dont see word like that in my gradle file.

My Gradle File (PROJECT):-

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My build.gradle (Module:app): This the my second gradle file

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
 compileSdkVersion 28
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.dhruv.testhello"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
 }

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
 }
```

Comment: this is your project level build.gradle. There is another build.gradle which  at your app module level.

Comment: sill that file also dosnt helps!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem. I searched so much and I finally found that `appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3` has some bug with "Design View" part of Android Studio.

So I suggest to change `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3` to `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1` version and then click File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart. Volla everything is OK.

Of course you should have internet access to download `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1`

Comment: I too have the same structure of code as mentioned above and I have changed the version from 28.0.0-alpha3 to 28.0.0-alpha1(had internet connection), but still its not getting build successful.

Comment: Worked like a miracle

Answer (score 3):

I was helped by Hossein Seifi's reply but with a change

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

and click File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: What kind of change you are doing ? The same answer as Hossein Seifie

Answer (score 3):

#### Update 2

As you can see in [support 28.0.0 release notes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions).

> This will be the last feature release under the android.support
> packaging, and developers are encouraged to migrate to AndroidX 1.0.0

Android will not update support libraries from now. So I suggest you [migrate to androidx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/6891563) before they deprecated support libraries.

#### Update

Support 28.0.0 is released, so you can use this stable version.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

I suggest never use alpha versions, because alpha, beta versions have bugs, that are testing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

module app gradle file looks like this...In your file you are missing **buildToolsVersion**, adding this may help you

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
  //changes
  compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.dhruv.testhello"
   minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
 }

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

//changes
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
 }
```

Comment: i also got some error after updating android studio to 3.1.2 and it solved when i updated my buildsToolsVersion as it 3.1.2 version requires 27.0.3 buildstoolsversion

Comment: Render Problem:
Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.

Comment: Failed to instantiate one or more classes

Comment: create a new project and see whether there is same error??

Answer (score 0):

In styles.xml,

Changing the theme from Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar to Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

yes its work,

implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
to

implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'

After that got to File and  click -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: Please consider using [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to improve the clarity of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this answer **Android Studio 3.1.4** is out with **Android Support 28.0.0 Release Candidate(Potential Final, Beta)** so please update.
Well, here is a config that will certainly work for you.

```
targetSdkVersion 28
com.android.support:*:28.0.0-rc01
```

Where * is the resource type.

Answer (score 0):

Open, `res>values>styles.xml`,  here you will find a line:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

replace the line with:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

That means: Add the word "Base." starting the name of the parent theme.

Answer (score -2):

Open, res --> values --> styles.xml, here you will find a line like this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

change it to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

In otherwords, change DarkActionBar to NoActionBar