# Android Studio Theme editor not showing previews?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am doing android development. I could not solve this problem.

[image: Here it is Screenshot]

I've tried making a new project and see what is happening there, but it's still not showing any preview.

I feel like I'm missing something silly.

Comment: Seems to be a bug https://stackoverflow.com/q/50777139/2308683

Comment: Can you post your layout file

Comment: and it works when app is running on device?

Comment: Yes @SahdeepSingh

Comment: In the top right corner of the layout pane, you have a red icon which means there's layout errors. What are they?

Comment: Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error. @cricket_007

Comment: <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I am best"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

Comment: Can you please show your gradle dependencies? https://stackoverflow.com/q/44449275/2308683

Comment: Why downvote? Please type reason in comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have answered this problem in this post:

[After Updating Android studio to 3.1.2 , I get "Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error. "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736578/after-updating-android-studio-to-3-1-2-i-get-failed-to-load-appcompat-actionb/50750803#50750803)

It is some kind of bug. I had the same problem. I searched so much and I finally found that `appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3` has some bug with "Design View" part of Android Studio.

So I suggest to change `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3` to `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1` version in the `build.gradle (Module:app)` and then everything is OK.

Of course you should have internet access to download `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1`