# Android Studio - ActionBar not displayed in the preview

Tags: android, android-actionbar

The ActionBar is visible when running the app on the device, however it is not in the preview section.

In the preview:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNjAz.png

On the device:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjIHn.png

This is the styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

How can I make the ActionBar appear on the preview also?
Thank you.

Comment: Show your code, not images.

Comment: I added the styles.xml file. It's just the base template, I just don't know why it doesn't show the ActionBar on the preview.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using some sort of `appcompat-v7:28.0.0-*` version. I've just had the same problem. The solution for me was changing an implementation line in the build.gradle file (Module: app).

**Replace this**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01' (or anything like this)
```

**By this**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736578/after-updating-android-studio-to-3-1-2-i-get-failed-to-load-appcompat-actionb) post, some `appcompat-v7:28.0.0-*` versions have a bug with "Design View" part of Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with the same problem and I think found a solution

1. first open your layout editor window and click on the eye in the top left corner as shown below and then click on Show Layout Decorations

[image]

2. You can change your apptheme there as well and so your toolbar, actionbar and so on...

[image]

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this answer (making it -1). 'Show Layout Decorations' worked for me.