# Action bar and device frame not displayed in preview and design windows

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently updated android studio to version `3.3`.

**Problem**

Created a new project and found out that layout preview window is not showing `action bar` but it shows in the emulator when app runs in the emulator. Device frame also doesn't shows up in the preview and design window.

**Styles.xml file**

[image]

**Gradle Module dependencies**

[image]

**Design window**

[image]

**Question**

I want to see both action bar and device frame, how can i fix it?

Comment: What theme do you have selected for the Design tab?

Comment: Have you tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410005/android-actionbar-not-showing-in-the-development-preview)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Actionbar not showing in the development preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410005/android-actionbar-not-showing-in-the-development-preview)

Comment: @TheWanderer AppTheme default

Comment: @Nick have look at it [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089722/android-studio-actionbar-not-displayed-in-the-preview)

Comment: @Nick can you [edit] in a screenshot of the full Design window?

Comment: @DeepPatel thankyou, that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check this :

> **Change a setting for Show Layout Decorations (By Default it is unchecked, just check it and ActionBar will be there)**

[image]

> **Visible ActionBar**

[image]

Comment: In Android studio version 4.0.1 it is in the same place, but called "Show system UI"

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple....try this may be its work....

Go to gradle script>build gradle(module app) and
Replace this dependency:
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3 
To:
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1