# RecyclerView ItemDecoration broken with AndroidX

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, androidx, android-jetifier

I have a compiler issue when using `DividerItemDecoration` with a `RecyclerView` in an existing project we are updating to use AndroidX libraries.

The project unfortunately uses DataBinding, which may be part of the issue. We have some ugly code like this:

```
getBinding().myRecyclerField.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(...));
```

Which tells me

[image]

AS automatically adds the AndroidX import for the class and the android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration no longer seems to be available.

How should ItemDecorations be used with RecyclerViews now?

Do we need to manually replace the RecyclerView tag in every layout? (This has not been necessary for other views (eg toolbars)

Comment: You have migrated project, did you clean project after migrate?

Comment: Yes, It's been through several cycles of Clean + invalidate Caches as I fixed previous issues

Comment: Does all layout xml have `support.v7.widget.recyclerview` after migrate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually to solve this I did have to replace all usages of `RecyclerView` with the `androidx.recyclerview` package and ensuring that I have `android.enableJetifier=true` and `android.useAndroidX=true` in my gradle properties to make the libraries compatible

Support/Default RecyclerView and AndroidX RecyclerView components cannot be mixed

Answer (score 0):

Use always **Refractor > Migrate to AndroidX**, that will convert all imports, uses automatically.

It will add `android.enableJetifier=true` and `android.useAndroidX=true` too.

[Useful Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/6891563)