# Android Studio: Floating Action Button: elevation works, but not as it should

Tags: android, xml, floating-action-button, elevation, circleimage

I need Circle ImageView with Shadow(elevation) on version >=16, i decided to try FAB.

The problem: 
[If fabsize - normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEqPv.jpg)

If you choose fabCustomSize(75dp)>fabsize(normal) - working, but image are to small:
[fabcustomsize 75dp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMehz.jpg)

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBlueLightLight"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:backgroundTint="#C4C4C4"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:elevation="4dp"
            app:fabCustomSize="75dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:rippleColor="#25FAFAFA"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/mute_2"
            app:useCompatPadding="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

The other two buttons have the same code

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution 1

This solution works only for AndroidX, you can read [@answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/6891563) for migrating to AndroidX. Use `app:maxImageSize="50dp"` in your fab.

[image: output]

#### Solution 2

If you don't want to use AndroidX for now, then put this dimen in your `dimens.xml`

```
<dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">70dp</dimen>
```

#### Update

Don't set `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` if you are setting `app:fabCustomSize`. Then your fab will not be like square.

Comment: maxImageSize  is available in `AndroidX` package. You will migrate to `AndroidX` support library in future for sure, so you can do it now. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/6891563

Comment: I added a variable, it does the same thing as fabcustomsize, but the problem still remains.

The normal size of the image - beyound the border [https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEqPv.jpg].
Small image size - don't beyond, but i need normal size image.
By the way, why the images are not round, but some kind of oval image?

Comment: Which variable you added?

Comment: i change design_fab_image_size to "50" and fubcustomsize to "80" it works. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any issue remaining now?

Comment: it seems to be not

Comment: What about square shape?

Comment: Everything is normal. In the beginning, when I just added design_fab_image_size, nothing has changed. When added the value of the variable fabcustomsize - the beginning of something to change. A couple of times changed the values and now everything works. Picture of a normal size, does not go abroad, shadows are present