# How to add onTextChanged listener to an include layout xml by databinding in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding, addtextchangedlistener, android-include

I have an issue to add onTextChanged to a TextInputEditText in an **include layout**.

There is a base_edittext_view.xml as below:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryText"
    android:background="@drawable/textinputlayout_background"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/edittextItem"
        style="@style/TextStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/input_border_bottom"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_user"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLength="50"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_xlarge"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:textColor="@color/edittext_text_color"
        android:textColorHint="@color/edittext_hint_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
      />

   <!---->

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I want to add a onTextChanged listener to a layout which include base_edittext_view.xml.

```
android:onTextChanged="@{(text, start, before, count) -> viewModel.onTextChanged(text)}"
```

There is no problem for adding onClick to **include layout** but for onTextChanegd I don't know how I can achieve it.

Note:

```
     <include
                android:id="@+id/edittextEmail"
                layout="@layout/edittext_email_base_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_xxxxlarge"
                />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it by passing `onTextChanged` to included layout. See example -

**This is `base_edittext_view.xml`**

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="onTextChanged"
        type="androidx.databinding.adapters.TextViewBindingAdapter.OnTextChanged" />
</data>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
   ...            
   android:onTextChanged="@{onTextChanged}" />
```

Now you can pass `onTextChanged` to included layout like below.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        layout="@layout/base_edittext_view"
        app:onTextChanged="@{(text, start, before, count) -> viewModel.onTextChanged(text)}"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**-------------That's it!**

There can be MANY other ways to implement it. I would like to share you COMPLETE INFORMATION.

#### WAY 2

You can make another data variable in parent layout. And include it to included layout like above. Like below-

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="onTextChanged"
        type="androidx.databinding.adapters.TextViewBindingAdapter.OnTextChanged" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        layout="@layout/base_edittext_view"
        app:onTextChanged="@{onTextChanged}" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And then you can implement `OnTextChanged` in Activity/ViewModel (wherever you need).

```
binding.setOnTextChanged(new TextViewBindingAdapter.OnTextChanged() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // do you work.
    }
});
```

#### WAY 3

**OR if you don't want take another variable in parent layout,** then you can directly pass `onTextChanged` to included layout from Java/Kotlin class. See example-

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/includedEditText"
        layout="@layout/base_edittext_view"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then from Java class-

```
binding.includedEditText.setOnTextChanged(new TextViewBindingAdapter.OnTextChanged() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
     // your work
    }
});
```

There can be many other ways too. Like making custom method in ViewModel/Activity and call that method from layout.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. After migrating to Android X, your first solution worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to replace androidX package with old class. It would made you confused. And migration to AndroidX is good, but that solution works for old structure EditText too.

Comment: No, It's Ok. If I want to use Support libraries, what packages should I use instead of Android X ?

Comment: You will be clear after reading my this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/6891563