# Flutter Image Picker package is not working

Tags: android, flutter

I am using image_picker 0.5.2 package for uploading a picture, after I added that dependency into the project I am unable to build my project, getting an exception which is mentioned below. Please help me out.

```
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/2.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/3.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/4.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/5.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/6.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/7.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/8.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/9.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/10.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/11.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/12.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/13.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/14.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/15.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/16.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/17.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/18.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/19.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/20.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/21.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/22.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/23.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/24.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/25.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/26.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/27.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/28.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/29.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/30.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/31.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/32.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/33.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/34.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/35.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/36.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/37.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/38.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/39.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/40.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/41.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/42.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/43.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/44.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/45.jar, /Users/harshavardhan/Workspace/cargill_flutter/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/46.jar
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
*******************************************************************************************
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: actually, your error is `Error while merging dex archives` . take a look in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.

As mentioned in your trace, this error is because of AndroidX incompatibilities in your app. The [image_picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker#-changelog-tab-) plugin migrated to the latest AndroidX support libraries from version **0.5.0**.

For your app to work, you can either [migrate your app to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate), or if your app depends on any other package which has not been migrated to AndroidX yet, you can lock your image_picker plugin version to **0.4.12+1**, which uses the older support libraries.

Add this to your `pubspec.yaml` to use specific version of this plugin -

```
image_picker: 0.4.12+1
```

More about this [here](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies#version-constraints).

**UPDATE**

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/10959473) for an explanation about why migrate to AndroidX. Also, this official [blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/hello-world-androidx.html) explains everything regarding AndroidX.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That thing worked, but can u please tell me what's the use of migrating app into AndroidX?

Comment: I just updated my answer with references to some documentation which might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate to AndroidX for that particular version of the library to work.
Follow the steps in this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility) to go ahead with the migration.

Answer (score 0):

```
File _image;   

 final images=ImagePicker();
Future getImage()async {    
var Image=await images.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera); 
 setState(() {   
   _image=File(Image.path); 
});   }
```

and when you want to Use the
`_image` which stored the `image` path:

```
  Container( 
 height: 180, 
 width: 180,
     child: ClipRRect(child: _image==null?Center(child: Text('Please Upload a pic'),):Image.file(_image,fit: BoxFit.fill,),),
```

when you initially run the program the _image variable is not containing the image path  actually the path is empty or null and the error appears so do
`_image==null?Center(child: Text('Please Upload a pic'),):`
it tells flutter if the path is null and not chossed show my manual message
you will see Please upload a pic in the container when you choose the image the File(Image.path); will generate an appropriate path and your pic will appear, thankyou,