# Manifest merger failed when using leakcanary 2.0 alpha 2

Tags: android, androidx, leakcanary

I am using [leakcanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) `1.6.3` in my project to find memory-leaks without any problem using:

```
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.6.3'
```

Now I want to update it to `leakcanary 2.0 alpha 2` using:

```
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.0-alpha-2
```

But when I try to build project, it gives me `manifest merger failed`.

```
ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-50:19 to override.
```

How do I fix this error?

**Update:** I am using `android.support` libraries in my project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research in `leakcanary 2.0 alpha 2` code, I found that the new version of library uses `androidx` libraries but I am using `android.support` libraries in my project. If I refactor my project to use `androidx` then no error occur.

It seems that:

- A project using `androidx` can use a library that uses `android.support`
- But a project using `android.support` can not use a library that uses `androidx`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/10284292) SO answer explain `androidx` and how to migrate your project to `androidx`.