# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.0

Tags: android, gradle

> > I have installed android 3.4.1 and after that i was setting up my android sdk 29
> >     after that got stop and shows this error.

**ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.0**
could you please help me out.

> build gradle module
>       apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testing"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

> build gardle project

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: there is no support lib 29.0.0

Answer (score 13):

With the release of `Android 9.0 (API level 28)` there is a new version of the support library called [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) which is part of [Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack).

Support Library version 28.0.0 will be the last feature release under the `android.support` packaging, and developers are encouraged to migrate to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)

You can continue to use the support library. Historical artifacts (those versioned 27 and earlier, and packaged as `android.support.*`) will remain available on Google Maven. However, all new library development will occur in the [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) library.

for more androidx info please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55849025/4649110)

Comment: Thanks Basi, I got it.

Comment: So what did you replace it with?

I tried "implementation 'androidx.appcompat.app:29.0.0' ", but I got a 'Failed to resolve' error.

Comment: there is no support lib version 29.0.0

Comment: @rmutalik you have to convert your project to `androidX`

Comment: adding:                                                                                              org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true      to gradle.properties did the trick