# Import statements giving errors after migrating to androidx, How to fix them?

Tags: android

This import statements in the MainActivity are giving errors(after migration to androidx), what to do?

```
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Comment: You have to replace the import statements to comply with AndroidX libraries version. For more details, check this: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: while migrating to androidx, package names should be changed in every class automatically, why that didn't happen? I'm confused.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55849025/4649110

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please remove your all `appcompat-v7` and other implementation for `androidx` you need androidx libraries like below

```
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: after migration, All the package names were supposed to be changed automatically, but that didn't happen. So now I have to do it manually for all packages?

Comment: Any clue how to do so?

Comment: If your project is big then best approach is find and replace from whole project intend of changing on every single file. using `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `F` you can find from all file.

Answer (score 2):

As Vipul Prajapati said, I manually changed all the package names by going to:  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

searching for my existing package and then replacing by androidx specific ones.

I also made the following changes to my

> gradle.properties

file.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: Thanks for appreciation I'm glad to help you out.