# I want to add implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0', but show message error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, android-manifest, androidx

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute
>   application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.

I have try other version but still get the error

Comment: error says you are using 2 libraries, which are adding `appComponentFactory` to your resulting merged manifest. You need to select and force only one of them. To do that add `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory` to your `application` tag

Comment: please refactor to [androidx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55849025/4649110)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [official release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019) (and `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0` is in this release):

> **Warning:** This release is a **MAJOR** version update and breaking change.
>   The latest update to Google Play services and Firebase includes the following changes:

Migration from Android Support Libraries to Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries. Libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:

- Upgrade `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to v3.2.1 or later.
- **Upgrade `compileSdkVersion` to 28 or later.**
- Update your app **to use Jetpack (AndroidX)**; follow the instructions in Migrating to AndroidX.