# Why was a new version (17.0.0) of the Places SDK released if it is being shut down on July 29?

Tags: android, maps, google-places-api, google-places

This places SDK for Android was deprecated on Jan 29 and is going to be shut down on July 29th

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0
```

The dependency for the new version of the places SDK which a static client library is this -

```
com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0
```

So, why is a new version 17.0.0 for `play-services-location` available via maven and in the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) for June 17 2019?

I'm really confused by all these deprecations and new versions in the maps platform so any clarity will help. Thanks.

Comment: Go through https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx and https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/3395198

Answer (score 0):

This update is having mainly two reasons

1. Play services are becoming very heavy and they want to move many of the services to Jetpack and standalone APIs.
2. This change gives them more independance to develop and release individual modules and library.
3. More accurate and refined billing structure

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a counter q - So they updated the places sdk to use Jetpack even though it'll be shut down in a month?
Regarding your 2nd point - they had already separated the play libraries long back. 3rd pt - I dont understand; that does not change. I'm specifically talking about the release on June 17th.