# build.gradle issues in android studio

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-manifest

[image][image]Please how to fix this error? I am facing this issue.

```
   ERROR:
 Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91

 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-22:19 to override.
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Could you please edit your question and put the error message into a code block so it becomes more readable. And next to that you definitely need to share your code or config files relevant to this issue. People cannot help you by merely guessing what you might have done inside your code.

Comment: @MuhammadRashid please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839238/manifest-merger-failed-after-adding-firebase-core-version-17-0-0/56839510#56839510

Comment: i am searching this problem solution from last 4 days on StackOverflow,but depressed

Comment: Even i  when i want to post code , StackoverFlow show warnings

Comment: Even i  when i want to post code , StackoverFlow show warnings

Comment: @MuhammadRashidHi, This error occurs when you are trying to use different support libraries, could you please check on that and update to the latest one ie: android x