# Can't run the app after updated the firebase build version

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Updated the firebase cloud messaging Gradle file version from 17.4.0 to 19.0.1 failed with Gradle build issue

````
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'

ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:70:5-482:19 to override.```
````

Comment: Can you share your complete app level gradle file!

Comment: Try `Invalidate cache and Restart` and run the app again.

Comment: tried that one but not working

Comment: it occurs because of your project contain `support` library as well as `androidx` library. try to convert to `androidx`

Comment: use this for how to convert to [androidx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280090/what-is-androidx/55849025#55849025)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having problem with dependencies that do not depend on AndroidX.
See about migration to AndroidX [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate).

Explanation: You have some dependency that depends on `android support` (Old, deprecated), and some dependency that depends on `AndroidX`. So there is a conflict when merging them.
Force your dependencies to use `AndroidX` by adding the following to your `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Also,

> With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can quickly migrate an
>   existing project to use AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to
>   AndroidX from the menu bar.

Now, see this:
[Firebase release notes and mention to AndroidX](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_june_17_2019). The official docs that state you need to use AndroidX in these versions.

Edit, just to add a reminder:

Whenever updating dependencies, specially a major version (the first, most significant number on the version code), **read the release-notes**. Even more if you are dealing with an already released software. This might save some lives.

Comment: Maybe emphasize that your first link makes reference to the 'Refactor | Migrate to Android X' menu option to perform the migration in a single-click.

Answer (score 0):

You can find detailed error log about your merge issue if you select your manifest file in your project folder then change the bottom tab to "Merge Manifest".

Maybe it can help you to find out more. See attachment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cant have a support library and an androidx library. You must either convert to androidx or remove your androidx libs and use normal libs.