# Why is NPE occurred in SearchView only in API level 21 with the following attributes?

Tags: android

I'm using android.support.v7.widget.SearchView like the following code.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView 
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_search"
        android:closeIcon="@null"
        android:searchIcon="@null"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

NPE occurred only in api level 21 with the fatal log.

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setState(int[])' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.SearchView.updateCloseButton(SearchView.java:849)
        at android.widget.SearchView.updateViewsVisibility(SearchView.java:798)
```

I figure it happened 'cause I set attribute is null of closeIcon and searchIcon.

How can I solve this problem wisely?

Comment: SUGGESTION:: modify your gradle.properties, build.gradle, *.java source and *.xml layouts to use androidx instead of android.support.

Comment: It's quite hard to change it quickly. I'll try it later. Is there another solution?

Comment: check null before using it.

Comment: android studio has a menu to do that for you. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280090/what-is-androidx

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following code.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView 
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        style="@style/LanguageSearchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_search"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Actually I made style for api level 21 in value-v21/styles.xml.

```
    <style name="LanguageSearchView">
        <item name="closeIcon">@null</item>
        <item name="searchIcon">@null</item>
    </style>
```

All api level except for 21, they will use the following style in value/styles.xml.

```
    <style name="LanguageSearchView">
        <item name="android:closeIcon">@null</item>
        <item name="android:searchIcon">@null</item>
    </style>
```

I just know with prefix of android is framework attribute, 
otherwise it's own application attribute.

But I'm still confusing about this solution.
Anyone who can explain it clearly?

Comment: Got the same crash here. Do you have any reference to your solution? And does it really work? Thanks.