# Need to add import androidx.core.view.children

Tags: android, kotlin

Downloaded a demo to check something inside it these imports works

```
import androidx.core.view.children
import androidx.core.animation.doOnEnd
import androidx.core.animation.doOnStart
```

but i can't use inside my project , it gives me error with `children` and `animation`

> Unresolved reference: animation

BTW i added AndroidX from this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58134686/8669531

if this will make a difference

Comment: Try adding `implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0"` and remove `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2`

Comment: hi @EpicPandaForce `import androidx.core.view.children` not compiles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are Android-ktx Packages. You can read on any [blog](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5576-android-ktx-tutorial-getting-started) about android-ktx.

Implement KTX :

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0"
```

This is releases of [Android-KTX](https://github.com/android/android-ktx/releases)

Comment: this works for the animation but `import androidx.core.view.children` still not works

Comment: I posted proper version but confused with EpicPanda Version

Comment: now i have `Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option`