# Faild to resolve androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4

Tags: android, firebase

I  got some error in **build.gradle** file like below:

[image]

What to do next?

Answer (score 0):

remove that dependency `androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4`  and use this dependency:

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

And for rest of the error recycleview and cardview:(remove that two dependency and add following for two)

remove this-->:`Failed to resolve: com.google.android.material:material-rc01:1.0.0`

use the dependency:(this dependency use for both recycleview and cardview ,etc)

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is version available `1.0.0` for `androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4`.

so do it in your gradle -

`implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"`

If you are migrating to AndroidX then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/6891563).

**For the new question**

[Check maven page.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material?repo=google)

You can use stable version -

`implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"`

Comment: What's the confusion? Is this related to link AndroidX?