# No changes after using Migrate to AndroidX option

Tags: xamarin.android, nuget-package, androidx

I am trying to Migrate our app to AndroidX.
**"Migrate to AndroidX"** option is not migrating the support packages to AndroidX.
No changes found in **packages.config**.

Can anyone help me on this or Am I missing  any step?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You can try migrating it manually, Remove all SupportV4 and V7 packages and install the androidX alternates https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/2500027

Answer (score 0):

When you use the migration tools in the visual studio, it will not change the nuget packages added by yourself and these packages don't support androidx libraries.

So you may need to open the nuget package manager to check the nuget package's version you had added into your project. And then select the version which support androidx and update it.

Comment: Zhang, I made a trial by migrating packages.config to PackageReferences. And then used Migrate to AndroidX option, it did installed AndroidX packages but with preview versions. So is that we should use PackageReferences hereafter in Xamarin. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: I have never used the packages.config, but according to the official document, it must be located in a project root. In addition, could you check if the the version number of these packages support the androidx libraries or not?@Bhargavi